# Arrange rectangular shapes sent to back or front

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rectangles, powerpacks

Is there any way to arrange `RectangleShape` controls to send them to the back and to the front in VB.NET.  I need to change their Z-axis order so I can change which rectangle is in front.  Here's an image of my form:

[image]

I would like to send the small rectangular shape behind the blue rectangle.  I'd like to be able to do it from the code at run-time.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? How have you created the layout?

Comment: this is WinForms. without layout.

Comment: Do you want to change the z-order at run-time in code, or are you just asking how to do it in the form designer?

Comment: Are the rectangles controls?  If so, what type of control are they?  If not, how are you drawing them?  Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Rectangles are not controls.
I am drawing with the help of drag n drop from toolbox in visual studio in a windows form application using vb.net.

Comment: Dragging and dropping what?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Dragging RectangleShape from toolbox and droping it on form.

Comment: So it is a control then.  Is it the [RectangleShape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.rectangleshape.aspx) control from the [Visual Basic Power Packs Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx)?

Comment: Yes it is a control in vb.net,but controls can be arranged and i cannot arrange RectangleShape.

Comment: I updated your question to reflect those details and voted it up.  It's a great question actually.  I've never used those Power Packs shape controls, so I didn't realize that they acted funny like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape controls from the [Visual Basic Power Packs Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx) library are not added directly to the form's `Controls` collection.  Instead, they are added to a special [`ShapeContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecontainer.aspx) control.  Normally the container is called `ShapeContainer1`, but if not, you can find it's name by looking at your form's `.Designer.vb` file.

All of the shapes are stored in the [`ShapeContainer1.Shapes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shapecollection.aspx) collection.  In order to change the Z-order of the shapes, you need to change the order that they are referenced by that collection.  In other words, you need to change their index.  The one at index 0 is considered to be the one in front.  Therefore, to send a shape to the front, you need to change its index to 0, like this:

```
ShapeContainer1.Shapes.SetChildIndex(RectangleShape1, 0)
ShapeContainer1.Refresh()
```

You need to call `Refresh` after you change the index to force the shapes to be immediately redrawn.

If you do want to change them at design time, since there is no way to change the order via the designer, you have to manually change the `.Designer.vb` file for your form.  For instance, you could change this line in your `InitializeComponents` method from this:

```
Me.ShapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Shape() {Me.RectangleShape2, Me.RectangleShape1})
```

To this:

```
Me.ShapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Shape() {Me.RectangleShape1, Me.RectangleShape2})
```

Comment: thanks for the  information about changing z-index of shapes.
:)